# Using Filters to show only the right posts - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to reveal the post count of the topic and I need to use ng-filter to do this. Unluckily I haven't gotten it to work yet here's the filter:

```
<span class="post-count" ng-init="posts = (posts | filter: { TopicId : topic.TopicId}:true)">
    {{posts.length}} posts
</span>
```

So there's an attribute in Post called TopicId, which is the foreign key to the Topic.

The app.js is rather simple:

```
   $scope.getPosts = function () {
        Post.query({
        },
       function (data) {
           $scope.posts = data;
       });
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to use filter on a giant array of all posts of all topics? For me it sounds like the posts of each topic should be a field of each topic object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use filter on html it self. Your `ng-init` expression is evaluated only once that is your problem, at the time of rendering html

```
<span class="post-count">
    {{(posts | filter: { TopicId : topic.TopicId}:true).length}} posts
</span>
```